# Laravel echo for a NON Auth::User ID

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to work out if the following is possible:

I understand you can echo data in a blade via **{{ Auth::user()->email }}** to get email, **{{ Auth::user()->name }}** to get name, **{{Auth::user()->id }}** to get user ID etc.. and this is for the current logged in user.

But what i am trying to achieve is, if i type in a 'name' into a text field in a basic one field form, is there any way that i can have it dynamically show an echo of that 'name' related users ID, even though it is not that of the Auth::User ?

**For Example:** User ID: **1** with 'name' as **ROGERHELLO** can type in the 'name' **POTATOHEAD** and have it echo it's relative ID visible on the page which could be ID: **5**?

I have searched about but cant seem to find a clear answer.. and hopefully this post can help others with a similar query in the future..

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Does this have anything to do with authentication?  Doesn't seem like it so I don't know why you'd be so interested in Auth::user().  Why wouldn't you just query the users for the matching name using the User model?

Comment: You would have to make an ajax call that will populate some text where ever you want.. If you know what I'm saying. For example you type name ROGER and it echoes id of that user if he exists

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to be able to search for users. If that is the case, try this:

```
//in Controller
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $keyword = $request->get('search');
    $data = [];

    if (!empty($keyword)) {
        //you can search for anything here
        $data['users'] = User::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere('occupation', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
            ->get();
    } else {
        //return a response to require an input 
    }

    return view('users.search', $data);
}
```

You can now display the search results on the view (`users.search`) returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

// Make an ajax request when you submit the frontend input form
// Send a post parameter 'username'

public function searchByUsername(Request $request)
{
    // Validate
    $request->validate([ 'username' => 'required|string']);

    // Search in username
    $userIds = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->username. '%')
        ->select('id')
        ->get();

    // Return json response for ajax
    return response()->json(compact($userIds), 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. It will come out quite simply

```
public function search()
    {
        $search_phrase = Input::get('q');
        $search_results = User::where('name', 'like', '%' . $search_phrase . '%')->paginate(6);

        return view('search.users', compact('search_results', 'search_phrase'));
    }
```

But you need use Input Facades:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```